# Tortoise Subversion - undo update

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a folder on my machine, but I had deliberly kept out of sync with the main project (I should have branched, but didn't)

I have now gone and updated this folder to the latest version, forgetting that I shouldn't do that.

Is it possible to undo this update, and go back to the state I was in before the update?
Or, (as I closed the update window), can I see what files were updated/added?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use "`Update to Revision`" and enter the revision your working copy was at before the update.

If you don't know the exact revision, you can use the log dialog to narrow it down.

And there's a log file which should have a list of all the files that were updated:
`Settings dialog->Saved Data->Action log`: click on the "`Show`" button.

Answer (score 1):

Use "update to revision" feature. 
See [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-cli-main.html)
for details

Comment: I see if I can find what revision it was in before the update.

Comment: @mp3duck use `svn log` to get that. See [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html)

Comment: @Nishant I am not a huge expert in SVN it seems. Where do I go to enter that command line?

Comment: @mp3duck -- there are provision to see history in Tortoise as well... unfortunately I do not have it installed... but it basically does the same thing.. shows all the updates ever done. But now thinking... unfortunately.. you can't see what files in your local-machine has been updated.. but you'd have an idea what were the changes in recent past... and roll back the files of interest.

Comment: @mp3duck -- If you want to do it on command line you's have to install SVN client like [SlikSVN](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download) or Subversion on your machine. Then open console/cmd, CD to your code directory or directory of interested... and just type `svn log`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the log. Click on the "Show log" option which will show you all of the updates you have made. Right-Click on any one of the revisions you would like to revert to and choose either the "Revert to this Revision" option or any others that suit your needs.

There will be an area at the bottom showing which files were added.

Comment: log just shows the last round of commits. The folder has not had all the latest updates for quite a while, and I've suddenly loaded them all in :|

Comment: That's unfortunate. I'm not sure if I can help. Sorry.

Comment: Tortoise has a `Show All` button in the window you get from `Show log` - just use this and you get *all* log entries. There is also a `Next 100` button...

Answer (score 0):

I had to explicitly following this sequence:

> svn update

(which pulled in lots of recent updates, including those i wasn't ready for in production, damn!)

> svn log | less

checked which update I wish to revert to

> svn -r REVISION

that did the necessary time travel, into a secure past :-)